# MySQL return parent when all child records meet criteria

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL statement almost working. I just need one tweak to get it fully working but I can't figure out how to do it.

I want to return all the rows from my parent table that have a child record, but only if all child statuses are 1. The child IDs are in a single comma separated field on the parent table.

Here is how my tables look

```
parent
    ID    IDS
    1     1001,1003,1004 
    2     1003, 1005

child
    ID    STATUS
    1001  1
    1003  1
    1004  0
    1005  1
```

I'd like the query to return just parent ID 2 because child records 1003 & 1005 are both status 1. I don't want parent ID 1 returned because child record 1004 status is 0.

This is the SQL I have so far, which incorrectly returns both parent records. I think it is doing this because if any child records have a status of 1, it returns the parent.

```
SELECT * 
FROM parent p
INNER JOIN child c ON c.id IN (p.ids) AND c.status = 1
GROUP BY p.id
```

Is there an easy way of only returning the parent record if all child records are status 1?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this is not a good design. You should really store one to many relationships in another table.

Now, as far as answer to this is concerned, it can be done via below query:

```
select p.id
from parent p
where p.ids in (
    select group_concat(id) 
    from child 
    where p.ids like CONCAT('%', id, '%')
    and status = 1
    group by p.id
);
```

Here's [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29f21/12/0). 
Please note that it relies on how ids of child records are ordered when parent record is saved.

Comment: Thanks Darshan. I prefer my SQL though as it seems cleaner to me! I take your point about the one to many relationship, but that's the way the table is designed I'm afraid, so I just have to work with it :(

Answer (score 1):

The answer just came to me...I just need to flip to test, so rather than looking for child records with status 1, I need to NOT look for child records with status 0....

```
SELECT * 
FROM parent p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from child c WHERE c.id in (p.ids) and c.status = 0)
GROUP BY p.id
```